# Compute a subdivision graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to compute a subdivision graph of an arbitrary graph by adding one vertex in the middle of each edge of the graph.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple way that works for *undirected* graphs:

```
Graph[
 VertexList[g],
 Flatten[{#1 <-> mid[##], mid[##] <-> #2} & @@@ EdgeList[g]],
 VertexLabels -> Automatic
]
```

- It preserves the indices of the original graph's vertices.
- It works on edge-tagged multigraphs, but not on non-tagged multigraphs (see [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html))
- If you need it for both directed and undirected graphs, you will need to do a bit of extra work.
- The names of new vertices will be `mid[v1, v2]` where `v1 <-> v2` is the edge that is being subdivided. In edge tagged graphs, it will be `mid[v1, v2, tag]`. If you want a graph where vertex names are integers, use [`IndexGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IndexGraph.html) on the result.
- Any edge/vertex properties (such as edge weights) will be lost.
- Performance is not going to be very good, but it should be perfectly adequate for small graphs.

Example:

```
subdiv[g_?UndirectedGraphQ] :=
 Graph[
  VertexList[g],
  Flatten[{#1 <-> mid[##], mid[##] <-> #2} & @@@ EdgeList[g]]
 ]
```

```
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]
```

[image]

```
Nest[subdiv, g, 4]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your good answer. It very help me.It works for my examples like Peterson graph. I named the induced subdivision graph "A" and I perform the function Adjacency Matrix[A] but it doesn't work. In fact, I want to use the new graph induced from the first graph and find its spectrum or line graph or other thing about this graph. I appreciate if you  can help me. Thanks in advance for your aid.

Comment: In fact, in new graph vertex set have former vertex plus the new vertex in the middle of its edge

Comment: @user81376 Yes, that is correct. If you add new vertices, there will be new vertices :-) Is this not what you were asking for? What I tried to make sure of here was that the `k`th vertex of the old graph will still be the `k`th vertex of the new graph. Of course the new graph will have additional vertices as well.

Comment: @user81376 I just tried and functions like `AdjacencyMatrix` and `LineGraph` do work on `subdiv[g]`. Can you give a specific example of an operation that did not work for you on the subdivided graph? Also, please tell us which version of Mathematica you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I use the 12.1 version of mathematica and you're completely right. I was my wrong and it's work properly now.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[pG, gU]
pG[n_: 1][g_] := Module[{vc = PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ (List @@ #), 
     w = {1 - #, #} & /@ Subdivide[n + 1], 
     vl = Join[{#[[1]]}, Table[Subscript[v, #, i], {i, n}], {#[[-1]]}]}, 
    Graph[vl, Head[#] @@@ Partition[vl, 2, 1], VertexCoordinates -> (#.vc & /@ w)]] &;

gU[n_: 1][g_, options : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 GraphUnion[## & @@ (pG[n][g] /@ EdgeList[g]),
  options, 
  VertexSize -> {_ -> Large, Alternatives @@ VertexList[g] :> 1}, 
  VertexLabels -> {_ :> Placed["Name", Below], 
    Alternatives @@ VertexList[g] :> Placed["Name", Center]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  VertexCoordinates -> DeleteDuplicatesBy[First][Join @@ 
     (Thread[VertexList[pG[n][g]@#] -> GraphEmbedding[pG[n][g]@#]] & /@ EdgeList[g])]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
rg = RandomGraph[{10, 15}, ImageSize -> Large, VertexSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]];

Row[{rg, 
  gU[][rg, VertexStyle -> {Alternatives @@ VertexList[rg] -> Green}]},  Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
gU[5][rg, VertexSize -> {_ -> .5, Alternatives @@ VertexList[rg] :> 2}, 
 VertexStyle -> {Alternatives @@ VertexList[rg] -> Green}, 
 VertexLabels -> {_ :> None, Alternatives @@ VertexList[rg] :> Placed["Name", Center]}]
```

[image]

```
rgdirected = Graph[VertexList[rg], DirectedEdge @@@ EdgeList[rg], 
   VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[rg], VertexSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], ImageSize -> Large, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

Row[{rgdirected, 
  gU[][rgdirected, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   VertexStyle -> {Alternatives @@ VertexList[rgdirected ] -> Green}]}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
rgmixed = Graph[VertexList[rg], 
   ReplacePart[EdgeList[rg], 
    Thread[{RandomSample[Range[EdgeCount@rg], 5], 0}] -> DirectedEdge], 
   VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[rg], 
   VertexSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   ImageSize -> Large, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

Row[{rgmixed, 
  gU[][rgmixed, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   VertexStyle -> {Alternatives @@ VertexList[rgmixed] -> Green}]}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Does it need any special package to work?It doesn't work for me I just have the first graph after performing and it doesn't give me the new graph with new vertex in  the middle of the edge of the first graph. I appreciate if you help me. I want define subdivision graph for simple graph and use it for get some details about graph such as its eigenvalue or line graph . Thanks its advance for your time and did.